# Can I use Welch's t-test on proportion data?

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, mean, proportion

I have conducted a Welch t-test to see if the group means in a school's average progress 8 scores (a measure of education attainment) are different for rural and urban schools.

I also have data on the % students in each school who passed their maths GCSE, but I don't have data on the number of students in each school. Can I use a welch t-test on this % data or should I do something different to test there is a difference in group means for rural and urban schools?

Comment: No, you cannot use a Welch test. If you had the counts (or proportions plus total n) you could use a proportion test or similar, however if all you have is a proportion then you cannot test anything.

Comment: I disagree. On GCSE:  In an international forum, you can't assume that everyone knows what GCSE is! It's an exam taken around age 16 in British schools. Even if you have only proportions or percents for two samples of schools, then a Welch test doesn't seem too crazy. The proportions are just data points. You have no information on variability within schools, and don't need it for comparing schools. You might be slightly better off with a generalized linear model that takes account of the bounded nature of the variable.If some schools have 100% or nearly so you need to take account of that.

Comment: Conversely, despite being British I have no idea what "average progress 8 scores" are or how they behave, but similar comments may well apply.

Comment: Proportions vary between 0 and 1; percents vary between 0 and 100 -- in this context. Despite the underlying measures being essentially the same, the terms are not synonyms.

Comment: @user2974951, from my reading, $n$ is the total number of rural and urban schools as OP is comparing schools, not students. So I agree with Nick's comment.